# how to merge matrices in R with different number of rows

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I would like to merge several matrices using their row names.
These matrices do not have the same number of rows and columns.
For instance:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 3, 2)
rownames(m1) <- c("a","b","c")
m2 <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 2), 4, 2)
rownames(m2) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
m3 <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2,2)
rownames(m3) <- c("d", "e")

mlist <- list(m1, m2, m3)
```

For them I would like to get:

```
Row.names    V1.x    V2.x    V1.y    V2.y   V1.z    V2.z
        a     1       4       1       4      NA      NA
        b     2       5       2       5      NA      NA
        c     3       6       3       6      NA      NA
        d    NA      NA       5       2       1       3
        e    NA      NA      NA      NA       2       4
```

I have tried to use lapply with the function merge:

```
M <- lapply(mlist, merge, mlist, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
```

However, it did not work:

> Error in data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 2), c(1,  :
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4, 2

Is there an elegant way to merge these matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply a reduction (`?Reduce`) to the list of matrices, where the reduction is basically `merge`. The problem is that `merge(m1, m2, by = "row.names", all = T)` doesn't give you a new merged matrix with row names, but instead returns the row names in the first column. This is why we need additional logic in the reduction function.

```
Reduce(function(a,b) {
         res <- merge(a,b,by = "row.names", all = T); 
         rn <- res[,1]; # Row.names column of merge
         res <- res[,-1]; # Actual data
         row.names(res) <- rn; # Assign row.names
         return(res) # Return the merged data with proper row.names
       }, 
       mlist[-1], # Reduce (left-to-right) by applying function(a,b) repeatedly
       init = mlist[[1]] # Start with the first matrix
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

```
df <- mlist[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(mlist)) {
    df <- merge(df, mlist[[i]], by = "row.names", all=T)
    rownames(df) <- df$Row.names
    df <- df[ , !(names(df) %in% "Row.names")]  
}

  # V1.x V2.x V1.y V2.y V1 V2
# a    1    4    1    4 NA NA
# b    2    5    2    5 NA NA
# c    3    6    3    6 NA NA
# d   NA   NA    5    2  1  3
# e   NA   NA   NA   NA  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be conceptualised as a `reshape` operation if the right long-form `data.frame` is passed to the function:

```
tmp <- do.call(rbind, mlist)
tmp <- data.frame(tmp, id=rownames(tmp),
                  time=rep(seq_along(mlist),sapply(mlist,nrow)) )
reshape(tmp, direction="wide")

#  id X1.1 X2.1 X1.2 X2.2 X1.3 X2.3
#a  a    1    4    1    4   NA   NA
#b  b    2    5    2    5   NA   NA
#c  c    3    6    3    6   NA   NA
#d  d   NA   NA    5    2    1    3
#e  e   NA   NA   NA   NA    2    4
```